# C++ chrono epoch is 100000 times smaller?

Tags: c++, epoch, c++-chrono

THe code below returns number like `14517044`:

```
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
typedef std::chrono::milliseconds Milliseconds;
unsigned long res = std::chrono::duration_cast<Milliseconds>(Clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
printf("epoch %lu", res);
```

But http://www.epochconverter.com/ site shows numbers like `1426143327`, where as it is in seconds. So the epoch with Milliseconds has 8 digits and epoch with seconds has 10 digits?

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: I'm guessing your `unsigned long` can't hold that number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware - not all computers use the same date/time for their epoch.  Anyway, your problem is truncation of the value to 32 bits... it needs more.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
    typedef std::chrono::milliseconds Milliseconds;
    auto res = std::chrono::duration_cast<Milliseconds>(Clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    printf("garbage %lu\n", res);  // garbage
    printf("epoch printf %lld\n", (long long)res);
    std::cout << "epoch cout " << res << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
garbage 202650458
epoch printf 1426131792730
epoch cout 1426131792730
```

See it run [here](http://ideone.com/RT66R9)

Comment: Do you think `auto res` will be 64 bit for all platforms?

Comment: @Narek: I strongly suspect so, yes, but it's usually better to code in a way that avoids such assumptions.

Comment: @Narek, According to cppreference, `std::milliseconds` requires a "signed integer type of at least 45 bits". So that `%llu` should really be a `%lld` then if we're assuming a `long long`.

Comment: How to ensure 64 bit cross-platform? `long long` right?

Comment: @Narek `#include <cstdint>` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint)) and use `int64_t`.

Comment: @Narek, `long long` is standard as of C++11 and is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits.

Comment: Changing your answer from `auto res` to `long long res`.

Comment: @Narek: with all due respect, you shouldn't be presuming to edit my answer when I'm clearly an active user reading comments here, it's not a typo or other clear error or oversight, and you're able to give your side of things in comments or post your own answer.  I feel `auto` is a habit to be encouraged here, fundamentally removing the class of errors leading to the question.  That said, a comment like `// res will likely be long long` would be reasonable.

Comment: Tony you told that the problem is that I don't use 64 bit. I agree. You also told that you are not sure `auto` will be 64 bit on all platforms. I also know that `long long` should be. And after this comments you didn't edit, I have edited for future reader to see a cross-platform working code. Didn't meant to offend you, sorry. And thanks for you help!

Comment: @Narek: it's not important whether `auto` will be 64 bits on all platforms... what's important is that it will be *correct* on all platforms, which is what `auto` guarantees inherently.  Same goes for using `cout` instead of `printf`.  No offense taken anyway - just trying to explain what I believe to be the way things generally hang together on SO....  Cheers.

Comment: If it is not guaranteed to be 64 bit then how it will work on all platforms?

Comment: BTW don't you want to change `%llu` to `%lld` and `auto` to `long long`? :)

Comment: `auto res = std::chrono::duration_cast<Milliseconds>(Clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    log(">>>>>>>>>>> TimeUtiles::getTimestamp %llu", res);` does not work on Android.

Comment: @Narek *"If it is not guaranteed to be 64 bit then how it will work on all platforms?"* - it's guaranteed to be the same type returned by the `count()` function... that's inherently appropriate.  No matter what type you store the `.count()`-returned value in, you can't improve on the type it returns.

Comment: @Narek: "does not work on Android" - not much I can say about that when I don't know the implementation of `log`, but if you used C++ standard streams you wouldn't have such problems.  For example: `std::ostringstream oss; oss << res; log("getTimestamp %s", res.str().c_str());`.  It seems your libraries are overly C-like, forcing you to hard code a lot of type information that would ideally be avoided.  If you can't change that, by all means use a `long long` or `int64_t` and matching format.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Will check if `std::ostringstream oss; oss << res; log("getTimestamp %s", res.str().c_str());` works.

Comment: Update: In Android again prints small number like `22013997`. Here is the code: `auto res = std::chrono::duration_cast<Milliseconds>(Clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << res;
    log(">>>>>>>>>>> TimeUtiles::getTimestamp %s", ss.str().c_str());`

Comment: @Narek: perhaps run the code [here](http://ideone.com/oWuWTQ) - it displays the values and size of the timepoint/duration values at various points in their generation / conversion, as well as the value and size `auto` gives to `res`.  The output may highlight whether the correct value is being corrupted somewhere unexpected.

Comment: `cout` should not work on Android device. Hence, I used `log`, which works as `printf` and prints in `Logcat`. Let me change your code to use `log`.

Comment: @Narek: sure - if you're going to do that, you might also consider tagging the question `android` and making it clear atop the question that you're dealing with a non-compliant C++ implementation.  No point having people finding a Q&A here with what appears to be general C++ advice that's been hacked around to compensate for Android.  Cheers.

Comment: I leave this question as is and have created new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005351/android-ndk-chrono-epoch-is-not-correct

Comment: @Narek: good choice - I see it's already getting some attention from people familiar with Android.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, btw converting to milli decreases the number of `count()` from 14 digits to 8 digits.  C++ merely does not work on Android :).

Comment: I have tried `std::chrono::system_clock` instead of `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` and it worked on Android. So strange.