# Android NDK chrono epoch is not correct (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, c++-chrono

The code below does not print epoch.

```
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
typedef std::chrono::milliseconds Milliseconds;
auto res = std::chrono::duration_cast<Milliseconds>(Clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
std::stringstream ss;
ss << res;
printf(">>>>>>>>>>> TimeUtiles::getTimestamp %s", ss.str().c_str());
```

I use NDK r9d and selected NDK toolchain version was 4.8 !

EDIT:

Changed `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` to `std::chrono::system_clock`and it worked. Why?

Comment: What does it print? What is `Milliseconds`? What is `Clock`? There is more recent versions of the NDK by the way.

Comment: @Drop It prints only 8 digits so overflowed garbage.

Answer (score 7):

`system_clock` is like a watch (the thing on your wrist before smart phones took over the planet). It can tell you the time of day. And because no clock keeps perfect time, it sometimes asks another clock what time it is and makes tiny adjustments to itself to stay accurate.

`steady_clock` is like a stopwatch. It is great for timing a runner on a lap, or timing your function. It never adjusts itself, but strives to mark one second per second as best it can. But it has no idea what the time of day is, or even what day of the year.

`high_resolution_clock` also has no relationship to any human calendar or time system, and is allowed to be a `typedef` to either `system_clock` or `steady_clock`. And in practice, it always is a `typedef` to one of these clocks.

On your system, `high_resolution_clock` is evidently the same type as `steady_clock`.